# Semidirect product group isomorphic to Dihedral group.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

[image]

Really having trouble with semi-direct products. Why is {$[1]$,$[-1]$} a subgroup? Struggling a bit with notation too. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: $\{[-1],[1]\}$ form a subgroup because multiplication by them is closed.  $[1][1]=[1]$, $[1][-1]=[-1]$, $[-1][1]=[-1]$, $[-1][-1]=[1]$.  Recall that the notation $\mathbb{Z}_n^\times$ means that we are taking integers mod $n$ and our operation is multiplication.

Comment: And n-1 is always in $Z_n^X$?

Comment: The elements of $\mathbb{Z}_n^\times$ are the integers mod $n$ which are relatively prime to $n$, $n-1$ is always relatively prime to $n$, so $[n-1]=[-1]\in\mathbb{Z}_n^\times$.